# Trying to select single elements within a class. Not working with "jQuery(this).next"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select only one element with the class name `postcode-overlay-not` using `jQuery(this).next()` which has worked for me in similar situations in the past. This time it does not seem to be working. I have tried using `.prev()` and this also has not worked.

Any help appreciated!

```
jQuery(".help-container .delivery-options__option .postcode-restrictions-not").click(function() {
    jQuery(this).next(".help-container .delivery-options__option .postcode-overlay-not").fadeIn("slow");
});

jQuery(".help-container .delivery-options__option .postcode-overlay-not .closing-x").click(function() {
    /*jQuery(".help-container .delivery-options__option .postcode-overlay").css("display", "none");*/
    jQuery(this).next(".help-container .delivery-options__option .postcode-overlay-not").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Comment: Try adding a `.first()` to the selector. If that doesn't help, please edit your question to include a relevant sample of your HTML

Comment: can you add html mark up?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan as you'll no doubt recall, `.next()` always gets the very next sibling regardless of the filter, so `.next().first()` will always be the same node (or none if a filter is applied).

Comment: @freedom-m yep, very good point. For some reason I read `nextAll()`. My bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.next()` gets just the very next DOM node, *then* compares it with the class(es) you've specified.

In your case, you've specified multiple, hierarchical classes which will never match a single node.

As you've not provided the HTML structure, here are some ideas to replace the `.next()`:

```
jQuery(".help-container .delivery-options__option .postcode-restrictions-not").click(function() {

    // remove (this) and just get from the top again
    // will likely match multiple
    jQuery(".help-container .delivery-options__option .postcode-overlay-not").fadeIn("slow");

    // Use (this).next, assuming the next is *exactly* as specified
    // unlikely, but depends
    jQuery(this).next(".postcode-overlay-not").fadeIn("slow");

    // Use nextAll().first()
    // will work if they are siblings
    jQuery(this).nextAll(".postcode-overlay-not").first().fadeIn("slow");

    // Use up to shared parent, then down
    // most likely to work, but depends on where others are
    jQuery(this).closest(".delivery-options__option").find(".postcode-overlay-not").fadeIn("slow");

});
```