# Removing sibling div when another span element contains specific text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to remove div with `class=".basket__item-cell.basket__item-qty"` only when `hidden-sku` is equal to ***"020-01119"***.

I've tried different approaches using .each(function) or .next() but could not get my head around it. In order to illustrate the example I've added the code bellow.

Please note that I can not add any id's or classes and the order of the rows may vary.

```js
(function($) {
  $('.hidden-sku').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().indexOf("020-01119") !== false;
  }).closest(".basket__item-cell.basket__item-name").next(".basket__item-cell.basket__item-qty").remove();
})(jQuery)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="basket__item-data basket__item-data--right">
  <div class="basket__item-cell basket__item-name">
    <h2 class="product-name">One </h2>
    <span class="hidden-sku">020-01119</span>
  </div>
  <div class="basket__item-cell basket__item-price">
    <span class="cart-price"><span class="price"><span class="currency"></span>18</span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="basket__item-cell basket__item-qty">
    <div class="input-combobox main-input-combobox input-combobox__with-qty" data-label="Qty" data-range-min="1" data-range-max="12">1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="basket__item-data basket__item-data--right">
  <div class="basket__item-cell basket__item-name">
    <h2 class="product-name">Two </h2>
    <span class="hidden-sku">020-01117</span>
  </div>
  <div class="basket__item-cell basket__item-price">
    <span class="cart-price"><span class="price"><span class="currency"></span>18</span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="basket__item-cell basket__item-qty">
    <div class="input-combobox main-input-combobox input-combobox__with-qty" data-label="Qty" data-range-min="1" data-range-max="12">2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="basket__item-data basket__item-data--right">
  <div class="basket__item-cell basket__item-name">
    <h2 class="product-name">Three </h2>
    <span class="hidden-sku">020-01118</span>
  </div>
  <div class="basket__item-cell basket__item-price">
    <span class="cart-price"><span class="price"><span class="currency"></span>18</span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="basket__item-cell basket__item-qty">
    <div class="input-combobox main-input-combobox input-combobox__with-qty" data-label="Qty" data-range-min="1" data-range-max="12">3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: change `.next` to `.nextAll` or `.nextAll(...).first()` if you're paranoid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to select single elements within a class. Not working with "jQuery(this).next"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39828074/trying-to-select-single-elements-within-a-class-not-working-with-jquerythis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job and arguably it's easier to understand what it's doing at glance.

I am also assuming the SKU is always going to be `020-01119` and never just containing that string? If that's not the case just put the indexOf back into the if condition.

```
(function($) {
  $('.basket__item-data').each(function () {
    var sku = $('.hidden-sku', this);

    if (sku.text() === '020-01119') {
      $('.basket__item-cell.basket__item-qty', this).remove();
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: offtopic: you don't need `$("selector", $(this))` you can just do `$("selector", this)` when this is a DOM node

Answer (score 1):

Watch out how you check the presence of string using `indexOf()`:

```
(function($) {
  $('.hidden-sku').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().indexOf("020-01119") > -1;
  }).closest(".basket__item-cell.basket__item-name").next(".basket__item-cell.basket__item-qty").remove();
})(jQuery)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.closest(".basket__item-cell.basket__item-name")
.next(".basket__item-cell.basket__item-qty")
.remove();
```

`.next()` gets just the very next DOM node, *then* compares it with the class(es) you've specified.

In your case, you have `-price` between `-name` and `-qty`

```
<div class="basket__item-cell basket__item-name">
<div class="basket__item-cell basket__item-price">
<div class="basket__item-cell basket__item-qty">
```

so it gets `-name`, then the next, which is `-price` and says, is this `-qty`, which it isn't, so gives you no matches for `.remove()`.

Here are some ideas to replace the .next():

```
// Use nextAll()
.closest(".basket__item-cell.basket__item-name")
.nextAll(".basket__item-cell.basket__item-qty")
.remove();

// Use nextAll().first() if you there might be more
.closest(".basket__item-cell.basket__item-name")
.nextAll(".basket__item-cell.basket__item-qty")
.first()
.remove();

// use .siblings 
.closest(".basket__item-cell.basket__item-name")
.siblings(".basket__item-cell.basket__item-qty")
.remove();

// Go up to parent, then down
// Most likely to work if the structure changes
.closest(".basket__item-cell.basket__item-name")
.parent()
.find(".basket__item-cell.basket__item-qty")
.remove();

// Go up to parent in one step, then down
// Most likely to work if the structure changes
.closest(".basket__item-data")
.find(".basket__item-cell.basket__item-qty")
.remove();
```